# Doctrine QueryBuilder don't working with DBRef

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

I currently have a field on a document of the posts collection which is a ReferenceOne to a collection of users. Querying on the shell `db.posts.findOne({"usuario_stream.$id": ObjectId("5012d7674dfbad7f4e000084")})` works fine, but using the QueryBuilder it simply doesn't works.

`$this->doctrine->createQueryBuilder('Documents\Posts')->field('usuario_stream.$id')->equals(new MongoId('5012d7674dfbad7f4e000084'))->eagerCursor(true)->getQuery()->execute();` on profiler shows `{ "$query" : { "usuario_stream.$id" : null }, "$orderby" : [ ] }`.

I'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It should work if you query on usuario_stream.$id using the ID as a string rather than an instance of MongoID:

```
->field('usuario_stream.$id')->equals('5012d7674dfbad7f4e000084')
```

Comment: Actually, I find it is the opposite - in my code I use ``->field('image.$id')->equals(new MongoId($image->getId()))`` and it works perfectly.